# Stop Jetty server with a debug attached

Tags: java, debugging, jetty

To stop Jetty server, I use the following:

```
java -DSTOP.PORT="$JETTY_STOP_PORT" -DSTOP.KEY=stop_jetty -jar $DIR/start.jar --stop
```

And it works just fine until there is a remote debug session attached to it.

Therefore, my question is - how to terminate all debug sessions before shutting down the Jetty server?

My Jetty version is 8.1.8.v20121106.